# Help understanding "口に出しては何も言わない"

Tags: grammar, meaning

I've seen this phrase used a few times and i don't think I get it. What meaning does the "ては" indicate? Here are examples from google:

> そんな彼女を直子はちらりと見たものの、口に出しては何も言わない。

> それは、現代人の共通認識のはずではあるまいか。
>   と、心の中で密かに抗議したものの、口に出しては何も言わない。
>   どうせ言っても、呆れ顔でたしなめられるだけだからだ。

This usage doesn't match any definitions of ては I can understand or find in a dictionary. What does it mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 「[口]{くち}に[出]{し}し**ては**[何]{なに}も[言]{い}わない」

「ては」, in this phrase, is just the 「て」 in the te-form of 「出す」 and the "contrast and emphasize" 「は」.

In other words, 「口に出し**ては**何も言わない」 is only an emphatic form of 「口に出し**て**何も言わない」.  = "***to not verbalize one's thought***"

If you take a close look at both your sentences, you will notice that in each sentence, a person has a thought or opinion about a matter but s/he is not expressing it verbally, correct?

I feel you might have thought too much into this 「ては」 as it actually has many different (and important) usages.